# Windows 7 PC freezes randomly (games, Internet, Skype)

Tags: windows-7, memory, freeze

I bought a custom PC recently and I'm facing this problem since then. The RAM which they provided gave BSODs. I replaced it with a new RAM module. The weird thing is that now there are no more BSODs but system freezes and hangs when I browse internet, play games, watch movies. I couldn't really identify a pattern. I've not yet tested the new RAM with Memtest. I also tried the same activities in a Linux environemnt (Linux Mint) and everything works fine out there. No freezes or lock ups.

During a freeze,
Mouse and Keyboard won't work.
CTRL + ALT + DEL won't help either
The only way to get out of it is to hold down the power button or hitting the reset button.

The drivers that came with PC are not compatible with Windows 7. I tried Driver Genius and installed NVidia drivers.

Here is the detailed system information.

```
--------------------------------------
 Summary
--------------------------------------
Computer Brand Name:                                            Hewlett-Packard Napa
Operating System:                                               Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate Build 7601
Service Pack:                                                   Service Pack 1
Processor:                                                      Intel Core 2 Duo E6550 (2333.3 MHz)
Motherboard:                                                    FOXCONN Napa (nVidia nForce 7100 630i (MCP73PV))
Memory:                                                         2 GBytes ()
Hard Drive:                                                     Hitachi HCT721010SLA360 (953,869 MBytes (1000 GB))
Optical Drive:                                                  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NSB0 (DVD+R DL)
Display Adapter:                                                nVIDIA GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i (MCP73PV) [Hewlett-Packard]
Audio Adapter:                                                  nVIDIA MCP73 - High Definition Audio Controller
Network Adapter:                                                nVIDIA MCP73 - LAN Controller
Monitor:                                                        LG 700B
--------------------------------------
Processor
--------------------------------------
CPU ID:                                                         000006FB
Code Name:                                                      Conroe-4M
CPU Stepping:                                                   G0
CPU Platform:                                                   LGA775 (FC-LGA6)
Microcode Update Revision:                                      B6
Core(s):                                                        2
Thread(s):                                                      2
Original Frequency:                                             2333.3 MHz
Current Frequency:                                              2316.3 MHz = 7.00 x 330.9 MHz @ 1.3500 V
CPU Core Temperature:                                           N/A
L1 Cache:                                                       Instruction: 32 KBytes, Data: 32 KBytes
L2 Cache:                                                       Integrated: 4 MBytes
CPU Thermal Design Power:                                       65 W
--------------------------------------
Motherboard
--------------------------------------
Model:                                                          FOXCONN Napa
Chipset:                                                        nVidia nForce 7100-630i (MCP73PV)
Slots:                                                          1xPCI, 2xPCI Express x1, 1xPCI     Express x16
PCI Express Version Supported:                                  v1.1
USB Version Supported:                                          v2.0
Super IO/LPC Chip:                                              ITE IT8718F
BIOS Manufacturer:                                              Phoenix - AwardBIOS v6.00PG, Hewlett-Packard
BIOS Date:                                                      05/08/09
BIOS Version:                                                   5.27
--------------------------------------
Memory
--------------------------------------
Module Number:                                                  0
Module Size:                                                    2048 MBytes
Memory Type:                                                    DDR2-SDRAM
Memory Speed:                                                   400.0 MHz (PC2-6400)
Module Manufacturer:                                            Unknown
Error Check/Correction:                                         None
Number Of Banks:                                                8
Number Of Ranks:                                                2
Supported CAS Latencies:                                        6.0, 5.0, 4.0
Min. RAS-to-CAS Delay:                                          15.00 ns
Min. Row Precharge Time:                                        15.00 ns
Min. RAS Pulse Width:                                           45 ns
Supported Module Timing at 400.0 MHz:                           6.0-6-6-18
Supported Module Timing at 333.3 MHz:                           5.0-5-5-15
Supported Module Timing at 266.7 MHz:                           4.0-4-4-12
Min. Row-Activate To Row-Activate Delay:                        7.50 ns
Write Recovery Time:                                            15.00 ns
Internal write to read command delay:                           7.50 ns
Internal read to precharge command delay:                       7.50 ns
Minimum Activate to Activate/Refresh Time:                      60.00 ns
Minimum Refresh to Activate/Refresh Command Period:             105.00 ns
Address and Command Setup Time Before Clock:                    0.10 ns
Address and Command Setup Time After Clock:                     0.17 ns
Data Input Setup Time Before Strobe:                            0.05 ns
Data Input Setup Time After Strobe:                             0.12 ns
--------------------------------------
Hard Drive
--------------------------------------
Drive Model:                                                    Hitachi HCT721010SLA360
Drive Controller:                                               Serial ATA 3Gb/s
Drive Serial Number:                                            STF6L7MS3RWLMK
Firmware Revision:                                              ST6OA31E
Drive Capacity:                                                 953,869 MBytes (1000 GB)
Media Rotation Rate:                                            7200 RPM
Temperature:                                                    N/A
Cache Buffer Size:                                              15001 KBytes
Number of Cylinders:                                            16383
Number of Heads:                                                16
Number of Sectors:                                              Unknown
Sectors Per Track:                                              63
Native Command Queuing:                                         Supported, Max. Depth: 32
TRIM Command:                                                   Not Supported
Write Cache:                                                    Present, Active
S.M.A.R.T. Feature:                                             Present, Active
Security Feature:                                               Present, Inactive
Removable Media Feature:                                        Not Present, Disabled
Power Management:                                               Present, Active
Advanced Power Management:                                      Present, Inactive
Packet Interface:                                               Not Present, Disabled
Look-Ahead Buffer:                                              Present, Active
Host Protected Area:                                            Present, Enabled
Power-Up In Standby:                                            Supported, Inactive
Automatic Acoustic Management:                                  Supported, Active
48-bit LBA:                                                     Supported, Active
--------------------------------------
Optical Drive
--------------------------------------
Drive Model:                                                    HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NSB0
Device Type:                                                    DVD+R DL
Drive Serial Number:                                            KKHDB794048
Firmware Revision:                                              LN00
Supported Disk Type (Read):                                     CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD-RAM, DVD+R DL
Supported Disk Type (Write):                                    CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD-RAM, DVD+R DL
--------------------------------------
Display Adapter
--------------------------------------
Video Card:                                                     nVIDIA GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i (MCP73PV) [Hewlett-Packard]
Video Chipset:                                                  nVIDIA GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i
Video Memory:                                                   128 MBytes of SDRAM
Bus Type:                                                       PCI
Video Chipset Revision:                                         A2
Memory Bus Width:                                               64-bit
GPU Temperature:                                                N/A
--------------------------------------
Audio Adapter
--------------------------------------
Audio Adapter:                                                  nVIDIA MCP73 - High Definition Audio Controller
High Definition Audio Codec:                                    RealTek ALC888
--------------------------------------
Network Adapter
--------------------------------------
Network Adapter:                                                nVIDIA MCP73 - LAN Controller
MAC Address:                                                    D0-27-88-63-23-41
Maximum Link Speed:                                             100 Mbps
--------------------------------------
Monitor
--------------------------------------
Monitor Name:                                                   LG 700B
Serial Number:                                                  1138
Date Of Manufacture:                                            Week: 2, Year: 2005
Max Vertical Size:                                              25 cm
Max Horizontal Size:                                            33 cm
Standby:                                                        Supported
Suspend:                                                        Supported
Standard Colour Space:                                          Not Supported
Preferred Timing Mode:                                          Supported
Default GTF Supported:                                          Not Supported
--------------------------------------
Time of this report: 2/4/2014 11:00:23 PM
HWiNFO32.dll: 4.1.7.0
```

I've also tried re-installing windows 7 and I'm 100% sure that there is no precense of malware or viruses.

Comment: please press the CAPS LOCK key druring the freeze. Does the light on the keyboard toggles or not?

Comment: @magicandre1981, I've not done that. I wonder how does it help? I'll do that and post the results. However, I've already tried pressing num lock during the freeze. The light was on right from the boot up and during the freeze. Pressing num lock didn't toggle light.

Comment: if the light doesn't toggle you have a hardware issue and not a software problem. Try all steps from scenario 3: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504#method3

Answer (score 0):

Start by eliminating some simple things.
First, get a baseline for temperatures while doing CPU intensive tasks.  Make sure they do not spike to high.

Then, for maintenance, blow out your computer if it is dusty.  Heat can cause elusive errors like memory errors, HDD errors, and lockups that could have you chasing a ghost (been there, done that)!  Re check temperatures just for your information.

Then test the HDD and fix errors, also run surface scan and fix errors.

Test for memory errors overnight, just as a quick check before moving on.

Finally, you might try to reload the OS to eliminate software issues if you haven't done so already (just install a fresh copy on an available partition or another HDD).

If it still has issues, then you need to move on to the next stage of troubleshooting where you (1) can reproduce the problem, then (2) make hardware changes and test and measure between EVERY hardware change to isolate the faulty hardware.

Comment: I recommend using Prime95 to test system for stability (and discover RAM problems) - options / torture test

Comment: Exactly, I would use prime95 and a memory tester at the same time to try to saturate your CPU, RAM, and memory controller to try to get the computer to freeze or BSOD on demand so you can troubleshoot hardware if the first steps do not provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

if Then test the HDD and fix errors, also run a surface scan and fix errors.
Test for memory errors overnight, just as a quick check before moving on.you might try to reload the OS to eliminate software issues if you haven't done so already you just install a fresh copy on an available partition or another HDD.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! OP pointed out that they had tried what you suggest: *"I've also tried re-installing windows 7"*- can you perhaps explain what makes your advice specific to this problem? Thanks!